# Is it correct to say "a significantly larger percentage"?

Tags: phrase-usage

Recently, I've read IELTS essay from British teacher about this:

UK residents spent a significantly larger percentage of their household budgets on leisure than their New Zealand counterparts.

It is quite strange for me to see this structure: a/an + adv + adj + noun.
Normally, I see the structure like: a/an + adj + adj + noun.

Could you please help me to explain this?

Thank you so much!

Comment: From my 5th grade Grammar school teacher..." An adverb modifies a verb, an adjective, or another adverb." The indefinite article pertains to the object noun.

Comment: *The **quickly** boiling water.* *The **gently** blowing breeze.* *A **profoundly** wise decision.* It's very common to see the pattern you think is strange.

Answer (score 0):

Would you find the following strange: "UK residents spent a **much** larger percentage of their household budgets on leisure than their New Zealand counterparts."?

I'm guessing you wouldn't; but "much" (in this context) is an adverb, just like "significantly."